# import React, from { useState } 'react'; not working

Tags: reactjs, react-fullstack

how to solve the problem, any idea form anyone?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is import React, {useState}  from 'react'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `import React, from { useState } 'react'`.

There is a typo here, since you are using `useState` you should import it like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

That's the correct way. Your 'from' is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```